# How to walk down an API when making a chainlink get request?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, chainlink

Am trying to make a chainlink Get>Bool httpget request on the fantasy premierleague API but keep getting a false response. my code is:
'''

```
function getGwstaus() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);

        request.add("get", " https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/");
        
        request.add("path", "events.5.is_next");
        
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }
```

[image]

> The API above passes a dictionary with a list of dictionaries. I have used what the chainlink documentation says but it seems not to work on this API.

Comment: I tried to run this on a local node, and the error given is 'EOF' which is quite vague. I noticed its a really large body that's returned, it could be that a result so large isn't supported. Suggesting raising an issue in the main repository, giving as much information as possible (ie the HTTP GET URL, what you're parsing, plus the error given in the node I specified above. The engineering team will then take a look at some stage https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/issues. As a fallback, you can look at creating an external adapter for this API, and returning smaller sets of data